# Java input/output and Scanner object

Tags: java

Below are two functions in my class, I want to first read the number of lines from a text file, then store the contents in an array. The problem I am having is that if I do not comment out `int aNumber = numOfObjects(newInput);` the array does not get stored and printed, it's as if numOfObjects function got to the end of the text file, and I can no longer access it. If I comment it out it works fine. I tried adding a second Scanner object but it didn't help. What can I do to make it work?

```
public void correctListItems(FileInputStream inputFile,FileOutputStream outputFile){

        newInput = new Scanner(inputFile);
        forCapturing = new Scanner(inputFile);


        int aNumber = numOfObjects(newInput); 
        System.out.println(aNumber); 
        for(int i=0; forCapturing.hasNextLine(); i++){ 

            publicationArray[i] = new Publication();
            publicationArray[i].publication_code = forCapturing.nextLong();
            publicationArray[i].publication_name = forCapturing.next();
            publicationArray[i].publication_year = forCapturing.nextInt();
            publicationArray[i].publication_authorname = forCapturing.next();
            publicationArray[i].publication_cost = forCapturing.nextDouble();
            publicationArray[i].publication_nbpages = forCapturing.nextInt();
            System.out.println(publicationArray[i]);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------\n");

        }
    }

private int numOfObjects(Scanner aScanner){ 
        int count = 0;
        while (aScanner.hasNextLine()){
            count++;
            aScanner.nextLine(); //if this isn't included you'll experience an infinite loop
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). With an `ArrayList` you do not need to know how many objects the file has so you would only have to read the file once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this as you want. i.e. by reading through the file 2 times. First to count and then to capture.

Just add below lines after your line `int aNumber = numOfObjects(newInput);` in `correctListItems` function.

```
public void correctListItems(FileInputStream inputFile,FileOutputStream outputFile){

    newInput = new Scanner(inputFile);


    int aNumber = numOfObjects(newInput); 
    newInput.close();
    inputFile.close();
    inputFile = new FileInputStream(
            new File(
                    "inputfile.txt"));
    System.out.println(aNumber); 
    forCapturing = new Scanner(inputFile);
    for(int i=0; forCapturing.hasNextLine(); i++){ 
    ....
    ....
```

So basically closing the scanner as well as file is important. And then creating the fileinputreader stream again will reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file. As you might already know, If the input file is not from the project folder, you have to give the complete path.

As a good process, its always better to close both the scanner object and file object after you're done, And then reinitialize the objects to start working on them again.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but the inputFile.close() and inputFile = new FileInputStream(new File("inputfile.txt"); doesn't seem to work, I get errors :\ Any idea why?

Comment: inputFile.close() throws an IOException and inputFile = new FileInputStream(new File("inputfile.txt") throws a file not found exception

The function above is in a different class than the driver program, FileInputStream inputFile links to a text file 'abc.txt', I'm not sure if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I didn't catch the exceptions properly. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the scanner class uses an iterator internally. This means that it needs to be closed at some point, which I cant find in your code. Therefore I would (1) add following line to the numOfObects function before the return: “aScanner.close()”. 

(2) I would create the second Scanner instance after you called the function, just to be sure. Hope it works.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The scanner doesn't move to the next line unless you call nextLine. So the loop is infinite since you're always on the first line.
But why do you need to know the number of objects in advance? Why not simply use a list instead of publicationArray?

Comment: Yeah it would be easier that way, we're told to use a static array and to create a private method to help count the elements in the array.

Comment: So because I use nextLine in my numOfObjects class it reaches the end?

Comment: Yes. Regarding the array, you could always use list and convert to array after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not exactly sure but I can be quite certain that the FileInputStream object once the bytes has been read by Scanner once, the scanner will have a token to indicate that a particular line has been read.

How about you change your code to:

```
public void correctListItems(FileInputStream inputFile,FileOutputStream outputFile){

        forCapturing = new Scanner(inputFile);

        for(int i=0; forCapturing.hasNextLine(); i++){ 

            publicationArray[i] = new Publication();
            publicationArray[i].publication_code = forCapturing.nextLong();
            publicationArray[i].publication_name = forCapturing.next();
            publicationArray[i].publication_year = forCapturing.nextInt();
            publicationArray[i].publication_authorname = forCapturing.next();
            publicationArray[i].publication_cost = forCapturing.nextDouble();
            publicationArray[i].publication_nbpages = forCapturing.nextInt();
            System.out.println(publicationArray[i]);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------\n");

        }
        System.out.println("Number of lines: "+ i);
    }
```

At least with this, you would not have to run 2 loops to the same set of data. better performance too and get the thing you need done in 1 round of a loop